# youtube_dl taking no part of the url entered even when the link is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl, python-3.9

I am giving my code first:

```
import youtube_dl
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showerror
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import pyglet
import validators

pyglet.font.add_file('BREAKBONE.ttf')

ytvdw = Tk()
download_path = StringVar()
video_link = StringVar()
ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'quiet': False,
            'extractaudio': True,  # only keep the audio
            'audioformat': "mp4",  # convert to wav
            'outtmpl': '%(id)s.mp4',  # name the file the ID of the video
            'noplaylist': True,  # only download single song, not playlist
            }

ytvdw.iconbitmap('swisstoollogo.ico')
ytvdw.title('YouTube Video Downloader - Swiss Tool Box')
ytvdw.geometry('500x500')
ytvdw.resizable(False, False)

heading = Label(ytvdw, text='YouTube Video Downloader', font=('BREAKBONE', 24, 'underline'))
heading.place(x=75, y=1)

info = Label(ytvdw,
            text='This program is used to download any YouTube Video \n you want to download. Just paste the '
                    'link in the box \n below then click on the start button', font=('BREAKBONE', 15))
info.place(x=5, y=50)

Label(ytvdw, text='Link', font=('BREAKBONE',20)).place(x=210, y=150)
link_entry = Entry(ytvdw, width=60, textvariable=video_link)
link_entry.place(x=25, y=185)

Label(ytvdw, text='Directory', font=('BREAKBONE', 20)).place(x=180, y=230)
dir_entry = Entry(ytvdw, width=60, textvariable=download_path)
dir_entry.place(x=25, y=265)

def link_check():
    link_check_var = str(link_entry.get())

    validated_link = validators.url(link_check_var)

    if validated_link is True:
        showinfo('Link Check', 'Sucessful! Your link is valid. You may continue!')
    
    elif validated_link is not False:
        showerror('Link Check', 'Sucessful! You link is not valid. Please check the link again!')
    else:
        showerror('Link Check', 'Some unexpected error occured. Please re-run the program.')

def browse_directory():
    download_directory = askdirectory(initialdir='C:/Users/Bhavyadeep/Desktop/YT Vid Download')

    download_path.set(download_directory)

def download_video():
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([zxt])
    
    showinfo('Video Downloaded', 'Your video has been downloaded in:'+ download_path)

yt_link = video_link.get()
zxt = yt_link.strip()


link_check_button = Button(ytvdw, text='Check!', command=link_check)
link_check_button.place(x=400, y=182)

browse_button = Button(ytvdw, text='Browse!', command=browse_directory)
browse_button.place(x=400, y=262)

start_button = Button(ytvdw, text='Download!', command=download_video)
start_button.place(x=200, y=300)

ytvdw.mainloop()
```

I am getting an error in using the youtube_dl module.
The final error:
`youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: '' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:" ) to search YouTube`

The link is valid after I check it and it works well. But after adding the link I get that error as if no part of the link was included.

Just in case the window freezes and crashes run the program in Debuging Mode.

The font url is below:
https://www.dafont.com/breakbone.font

I am kind off new to youtube_dl and haven't worked with it. Please help me!

Answer (score -1):

> elif validated_link is not False:

I think maybe it is

> is false

Comment: Hi, could you please add some detail on why that is and how this helps? This improves the readability and reusability of this answer.